# Show any open interval is a half open set?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

How do I show that any open interval is an half open set and use this to conclude that any open set is also half open?

I am in an introduction to proofs writing class.  I have a feeling I need to use the fact that an open set is a union of open intervals but I don't know that I am even going in the right direction... help getting started! I'd like to try to come up with the proof

Comment: What is the definition of a half-open set?

Comment: My definition of of *H*-open is a subset *U* of $\mathbf R$ is called an H-open set if $ U = \emptyset$ or if, for each $ x \in U$ , there is an H-open interval *I* such that $ x \in I \subseteq U$.

Comment: @AlyssaWallace yeah, maybe the second "H-open" in your definition should have been "half-open"? As in $[a,b)$, and $(a,b]$.

Comment: I know half-open intervals are in the form [a, b).  and as I read my definition of h-open I did type it correctly.  I think we are supposed to say that the U in the definition for half open stands for the usual definition of an open interval...

Answer (score 1):

Take any half open interval $(a,b)$, with $a<b$ (otherwise its empty and the conclusion is trivial). Let $x\in(a,b)$, this means $a<x<b$.

We can therefore find $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<c<x$. In particular, $x≥c$, which gives $x\in[c,b)\subset(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it directly. If $U$ is an open set then for any $c\in U$ there's an open interval $I=(a,b)\subseteq U$ such that $c\in I$. Or put another way $a<c<b$, now both $[c,b)$ and $(a,c]$ are subsets of $I$ and therefore subset of $U$ which means that $U$ is half-open.

Note that your definition would not need to explicitly mention $U=\emptyset$ as the other requirement is trivially fulfilled for the empty set.